# Label segmented cells with different colors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working with Matlab to extract cells from pathology images.
My codes successfully done the job and I can outline the cells by using 'bwperim'.
To outline the cell, my codes are:

```
perim=bwperim(selected_img);
r=img(:,:,1);
g=img(:,:,2);
b=img(:,:,3);
r(perim)=255;
g(perim)=0;
b(perim)=0;
img(:,:,1)=r;
img(:,:,2)=g;
img(:,:,3)=b;
```

And labeled the cells are:

[image]

But now I want to make the whole cell labeled with red, rather than just outline, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [`imfill`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html):

```
mask = imfill(permi, 'holes');
```